# How to find the height of a 2D coordinate inside a triangle made up of 3D points?

Tags: math, trigonometry

Lets say there is a right-angled triangle in 3D space, there is 3 x,y,z coordinates to make up this triangle.

And you have an x & z coordinate that you know is inside the bounds of the triangle in 2D space. How would you go about finding the y position of the coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let two perpenicular edges of triangle are base vectors `A` and `B`, right angle in vertex `C`. Any inner point might be represented as

```
P = C + a * A  + b * B
```

Make two equations for `x` and `z` coordinates in the plane

```
a * A.x  + b * B.x = P.x - C.x
a * A.z  + b * B.z = P.z - C.z
```

solve linear equation system for unknown coefficients `a` and `b`, then apply these coefficients to 3D case to get y-component

```
P.y = C.y + a * A.y + b * B.y
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, a question about how to calculate the a & b coefficients, what equation should I use to get a & b if I know the distance from the 3 coordinates? Sorry for sounding a bit incapable!

Comment: I added equation system in explicit form. It is for case `you have an x & z coordinate` as stated. `3 distances`  is fully different problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the ambiguity. Yes I do know the x & z coordinate, I was just trying to understand how to get the a & b coefficients. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: To solve the system - make  `a=(P.x - C.x - b * B.x)/A.x` from the first equation and substitute into the second one to get `b` value, then find `a` value